# Recognising user input char to String

Tags: string

```
choice = input.charAt(0);   
if (choice == 'y'){
condition
}
```

I originally had this so the input was recognised only by char. However, i've decided instead of 'y' i want a string, requiring the user to input yes. 
I changed choice from char to String choice;

```
choice = input.charAt(0);   
if (choice == "yes"){
condition
}
```

However for "input.charAt(0) i'm unsure of what i need to change.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(input.equals("yes"){
    // do something
}
```

That's it. But then the input needs to be *exactly* "yes". If you want it to ignore casing, you just use this:

```
if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"){
    // do something
}
```

Then the user can also enter "Yes" or "yEs", and it will still accept it.

If you also want to check for "no" and anything else the user could have written, do this:

```
if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"){
    // do something
}
else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
    // do something else
}else{
    // something other than "yes" or "no" was entered
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. Do you know how i'd do the same again but for no, in the same if statement. Then another for crash because if the user enters anything outside no or yes it'll crash. I guess it's something to do with else and elseif